# Get generic type parameter from class name in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm using `Jayway JsonPath` library, that has following static method

```
public static <T> T read(Object json, String jsonPath, Predicate... filters) {
    return parse(json).read(jsonPath, filters);
}
```

A valid call would be

```
Object document = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(jsonPayload);
desiredObject = JsonPath.<DesiredClass>read(document, "$.path1.path2");
```

Now, here is my problem. I have string representing className, so I get a class object from that, and would like to pass it as generic type parameter to this static method

```
entityClass = Class.forName("com.company.domain." + desiredClassName);
desiredObject = JsonPath.<WHAT-TO-PUT-HERE>read(document, "$.path1.path2.");
```

I tried - typecasting, `Class<entityClass>` etc but nothing worked. What could be the right syntax?

Comment: I don't think that's possible to do without reflection. Have you tried just calling `JsonPath.read(...` without any generics?

Answer (score 0):

you could use it like this:

```
JsonPath.parse(document).read(entityclass,"$.path1.path2");
```

Comment: The code snippet added in question is indeed part of json-path-2.2.0.jar. Check JsonPath.java and you will find a static method parse(java.lang.Object json) that returns DocumentContext . And then JsonContext.java has method "public <T> T read(String path, Predicate... filters)" at line 137. Here JsonContext implements DocumentContext

Comment: sorry i missed it but you could use the code i gave you that will give  you  an alternative from using static method read Of JsonPath

Comment: that will give you more flexibility